# Testing John Papa's controller calls to dataservice

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am learning BDD with Jasmine and Karma.

I'm following [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and I have some difficulties testing my code.

I want to test this kind of controller function (from John Papa's guide):

```
function getAvengers() {
    return dataservice.getAvengers()
        .then(function(data) {
            vm.avengers = data;
            return vm.avengers;
        });
}
```

With this factory:

```
function dataservice($http) {
    return {
        getAvengers: getAvengers
    };

    function getAvengers() {
        return $http.get('/api/maa')
            .then(getAvengersComplete)
            .catch(getAvengersFailed);

        function getAvengersComplete(response) {
            return response.data.results;
        }

        function getAvengersFailed(error) {
            // Fail
        }
    }
}
```

I've made these test:

```
describe("avengers controller", function() {

    var controller, avengers;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, _dataservice_) {
        dataserviceMock = _dataservice_;
        controller = _$controller_;
        vm = controller("AvengerController", { dataservice: dataserviceMock });
        $q = _$q_;
        rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        avengers = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}];
    }));

    it('should be created successfully', function () {
        expect(vm).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have called `dataservice.getAvengers`', function() {
        spyOn(dataserviceMock, 'getAvengers').and.callFake(function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            return deferred.promise;
        });
        vm.getAvengers();
        expect(dataserviceMock.getAvengers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    // What I'm trying to test
    // Test 1
    it('should have Avengers', function() {
        spyOn(dataserviceMock, 'getAvengers').and.callFake(function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve([{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]);
            return deferred.promise;
        );
        vm.getAvengers();
        expect(vm.avengers.length).toEqual(avengers.length);
    });
    // Test 2
    it('should have Avengers', function() {
        spyOn(dataserviceMock, 'getAvengers').and.returnValue(avengers);
        vm.getAvengers();
        expect(vm.avengers.length).toEqual(avengers.length);
    });
});
```

I tried two different ways but it didn't work and I can't figure out how to test that avengerController.getAvengers() defines vm.avengers equal to the returned data avengers from the factory call.

Comment: can you please elaborate what is not working? is it the test `should have Avengers` due to the promise?

Comment: Test 1 return "expected 0 to equal 2", and test 2 return "undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'dataservice.getAvengers().then(getAvengersComplete)')".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
it("should have avengers", function() {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            spyOn(dataserviceMock, 'getAvengers').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
            deferred.resolve(customers);
            vm.getAvengers();
            expect(dataserviceMock.getAvengers).toHaveBeenCalled();
            scope.$digest();
            expect(vm.avengers).toBeDefined();
            expect(vm.avengers).toEqual(avengers);
        });
```

I had to return a promise and use the scope.$digest() to simulate the scope life cycle as mentionned [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest).